# how to make a POST request in python and webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, webapp2

I am trying to make a POST request to the Health Graph API using python and google app engine with webapp2. I have seen an example where this is done as follows:

```
payload = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,}
req = requests.post(API_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data=payload)
```

but it seems that I can't use the requests module in google app engine. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Google's URL Fetch library on Appengine. Try this:

```
payload = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=API_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, payload = payload, method=urlfetch.POST)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick (with urbl -> url, of course). I had managed to get it working with urllib2 as well, but I think this is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on Linuxious answer. You'll need to encode the data using `urlencode` from `urllib`. Else you're get an error complaining that payload needs to be a string. Thus:

```
import urllib
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

payload = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
'code': code,
'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}

 payload= urllib.urlencode(payload)

 result = urlfetch.fetch(url=API_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, payload = payload, method=urlfetch.POST)
```